# Long stay France visa for minors

Tags: schengen, france, canadian-citizens

My wife and I have Long Stay Visa in the “entrepreneur / profession libérale” category from France, and already rented a house in Paris to live.

Two weeks ago our baby girl was born in Canada, and now we are planning to return to Paris in 6 weeks, I was wondering should we request a visa for our newborn baby? Or we should just go to Paris (She needs no visa for entry and staying for 90 days) or what?

I am not sure what should we do, Please let me know if anyone knows what to do.

Comment: This will depend on French national law. The only french rule that I could find was for an initial visa application (up to age 6, free of charge when traveling with a parent). If french law is the same as german law: up to the age of 16 will automatically be issued a residence permit if the parent(s) has a valid residence permit. So entering France with a Canadian passport, where no visa is required, and the registration of the child after arrival in France is the most likly procedure.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks. We are planning to do like what you said, to enter France and then register our baby. I am sure they won't deport a 2-month-old baby! :)